# how can i run a local server script from my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, web

i'm using javascript and html to create a webpage and i want it to run local powershell script on the server its running on. the purpose of this is having kind of a web ui for running usefull scripts in my domain instead of manually going to the file location and run it as a refular powershell script.

also, basically i have a gui app i made for some of those scripts so i just want it to be online so the rest of my team can access it and not only from my desktop.

i've searched all over the internet and couldn't find anything like what i need...

is there a way in javascript to run on demand a local ps file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an AJAX request from the client to your server (the one which host your scripts) can works.

This AJAX request will ask your server to run "name_of_the_script.ps".

https://www.itdroplets.com/run-a-powershell-script-from-php/